# How do you set a fiscal year?

Tags: civireport

Also - does changing a fiscal year change anything else outside of reporting and searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under admin - localization - date formats.

This link is old but suggests it's only for reports.

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=30822.0.html